# Consumir WebService WCP con proxy y Anonymous Autehntication

Tags: c#, http, wcf, binding, proxy

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que tiene dos partes, una aplicación de WCF, la cual se encuentra alojada en IIS. Dicha aplicación es consumida por otro aplicativo pero de escritorio.

Las aplicaciones funcionan a la perfección, tanto en el ambiente de desarrollo como en un ambiente de producción (conectándose al servidor por una ip pública). El inconveniente que estoy teniendo es que acabamos de empezar con un cliente, cuya red tiene un proxy, lo cual provoca que a la hora de consumir algún método del WCF nos devuelva el siguiente error:

> El servidor remoto devolvió una respuesta inesperada: (407) authenticationrequired.

Después de esto, me puse a investigar, hasta que encontré que se debe de configurar el proxy en el `binding`, por lo cual guiándome con un post que encontré desarrollé el siguiente código:

```
        private static ConnectivityClient getProxy()
    {
        ConnectivityClient client = new ConnectivityClient();
        var useProxy = Boolean.Parse(Util.GetAppSettings("useProxy")); //determina sí ocupa configuración proxy o no.
        var proxyAddress = Util.GetAppSettings("proxyAddress"); //define la dirección del proxy
        var proxyPort = Util.GetAppSettings("proxyPort"); //define el puerto del proxy
        if (useProxy)
        {
            var b = new BasicHttpBinding();

            b.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort));
            b.UseDefaultWebProxy = false; // !!!
            b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None; // !!!
            b.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None; // !!!
            b.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            client.Endpoint.Binding = b;
        }
        client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(getURL());
        return client;
    }
```

Ahora bien, sigue sin funcionar, ya que en caso de que configure el `BasicHttpSecurityMode` en `None` me vuelve a tirar el error de autenticación, sí lo configuro como Transport me dice que ocupa HTTPS (lo cual el servidor del WCF no tiene) y cualquier otro tipo me pide credenciales.

Según lo que he leído, este es un problema meramente del lado del cliente y no tiene ninguna relación con el WCF, ni con el IIS.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme en conocer la manera en que se pueda configurar el proxy y también configurar Credenciales como anónimas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el usuario que ejecuta el cliente sí tiene acceso a Internet, lo que resta es asociar sus credenciales al proxy. Esto lo puedes aplicar a través del archivo .config de la aplicación del siguiente modo:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

También es factible hacerlo mediante código, aunque no me gusta tanto esa alternativa si por configuración se puede resolver.

En el siguiente link se puede encontrar más detalle del tema...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stcheng/2008/12/03/wcfhow-to-supply-dedicated-credentials-for-webproxy-authentication-in-wcf-client/

Espero la información te sea de ayuda.